# Laravel: how to use laravel blade inside javascript?

Tags: javascript, laravel

Let's say i have data coming from my controller through Javascript.
So the data is paginated and i want display pagination result inside the javascript. I mean...I want to use the `links()` method inside javascript.

**Controller**

```
$schedules= DB::table('schedules')
                ->paginate(4);
```

**Javascript**,

```
success:function(schedules)
{
    console.log(schedules);
    $('#table').append(' <ul class="pager">'+{{  $schedules>links() }}+'</ul>');
})
```

But unfortunately not working, any help guys?

Comment: Couldn't you just pop the results in a div that's hidden then only show the div once the success is called?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44138773/4149985 This may also help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your blade syntax `{{ }}`:

```
    $('#table').append(' <ul class="pager">'+{{ + $schedules>links() }}+'</ul>');
```

Remove the extra plus `+` icon before `+ $schedules>links()` like so:

```
 $('#table').append(' <ul class="pager">'+{{ $schedules>links() }}+'</ul>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Push html paginate results from the controller, Enter the javascript code in the blade file, maybe

//controller

```
$paginate = '';
$paginate .= $datas->links();
```

//JS code in the blade file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
let paginate = '<div>';
    paginate += {!! json_encode($paginate) !!}
    paginate += '</div>'
consolelog(paginate)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just convert the collection to a JSON.

*Try this one:*

**Controller**

```
$schedules= DB::table('schedules')
                    ->paginate(4)->toArray();

return response()->json($schedules);
```

**Javascript Ajax**

```
success:function(schedules)
{
    console.log(schedules);
    $('#table').append(' <ul class="pager">'+schedules.links+'</ul>');
})
```

But in what I see, you're using the schedules also on your blade. In that case you can have a different function called for the ajax in your controller and different route.

Hope it helps!